# where does the virtual machine files are stored in Windows Azure and how to retrieve them with Azure SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net, azure-java-sdk

where are the virtual machine files stored in windows azure and how to retrieve them programmatically with Azure Java SDK?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "Virtual Machine Files"?

Comment: @GauravMantri We need to retrieve the virtual Datastores(terminology used in VMware) in Windows Azure.

Comment: A link for Virtual Datastores or some kind of explanation would certainly help finding equivalent in Azure VMs. Please update your question with more details.

Comment: I think Raja wants to retrieve the VHD.  I found this Datastore info: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/faq/virtual-datastore.html

Answer (score 0):

The Virtual Datastore is essentially the Azure storage account where your virtual machines are stored. It contains the OS and Data Disks that comprise the VM (as Hyper-V VHD's). You can download them using any number Azure Storage tools, or write your own using your SDK of preference (such as the Azure Java SDK).

Answer (score 0):

Raja - using the Java SDK you should.

1. Connect to your subscription. See [Brady's post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/getting-started-with-the-azure-java-management-libraries/).
2. Enumerate your Virtual Machines (and filter appropriately) using [ComputeManagementClient](http://dl.windowsazure.com/javadoc/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/compute/ComputeManagementClient.html).
3. For all Virtual Machines you care about look at their Disk collections and then using the URL of the VHD you can use the [StorageManagementClient](http://dl.windowsazure.com/javadoc/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/storage/StorageManagementClient.html) to download the VHD.

Note that you'd most likely want the VM switched off before doing the retrieval of the VHD.

Comment: Thank you. I was done with the 1st and 2nd points which you mentioned, already. Regarding the 3rd point can you provide the equivalent method to retrieve them?